# What is the state of GPT-3 for text classification in spanish?

Tags: nlp, text-classification

I would like to know if it is possible to reuse gpt-3 in a different language, Spanish in this case.

Do I need a gpt-3 model specifically trained with a Spanish corpus, or can I use transfer learning to produce Spanish text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GPT-3 is only available via an API and only to people who [apply for the access](https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=VsqMpNrmTkioFJyEllK8s0v5E5gdyQhOuZCXNuMR8i1UQjFWVTVUVEpGNkg3U1FNRDVVRFg3U0w4Vi4u). The model is too big to run it locally on any reasonable hardware and fine-tuning is thus hardly an option.

Given how well GPT-3 works machine translation, my guess is that it will work reasonably well for Spanish by default. However, if your task is text classification, you can do a much better job when using a pre-trained BERT-like model, [Hugginface's Transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) already have several [models for Spanish](https://huggingface.co/models?search=spanish).